# Can multiple mouse actions be added to a button? How?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So i have a ton of button on stage and id like to assign the same function to all the buttons.

I want the function itself to evaluate whether ot not the event received was a MOUSE_CLICK or a MOUSE_HOVER and based on the event do something...

What i have is something like this....

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option1'));
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option2'));
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option3'));
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option4'));
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option5')); // and so on for about 100 buttons

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER, makeListener('option1'));
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER, makeListener('option2'));
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER, makeListener('option3'));
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER, makeListener('option4'));
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_HOVER, makeListener('option5')); // and so on for about the same 100 buttons


 function makeListener(option: String): Function {
        return function (event: Event): void {
    // DO something
        }
    }
```

What I would like is something like this... (obviously it doesnt work)

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK || MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option1'));
btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK || MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option2'));
btn3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK || MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option3'));
btn4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK || MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option4'));
btn5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK || MouseEvent.CLICK, makeListener('option5')); // and so on for about 100 buttons

function makeListener(option: String): Function {
    return function (event: Event): void {
        if (event = MOUSE_CLICK){
        // DO something
        } else if(event = MOUSE_HOVER){
        // Do Something else
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is poor design and I would recommend you not go down this path. You need to step back and think why you want to have one function handle hover events and also handle click events.

Comment: It needs to have hover actions for User interface to offer feedback to the user, so for example, if I hover my mouse over a button, i want the status bar of my app to tell the user what will happen if he clicks it. And if he clicks it i want the actual thing to happen, does that make sence?

Seems like great design to me to let users know what they will be doing if they click on something. Do you have any alternative suggestions for achieving this?

Comment: It is actually bad design. You want 1 function to do it all basically. The first reason why is think of the next time you go to modify the code, when you change something in that function you can break things. for example your boss comes up and says I want to stop the hover events. Now to remove the hover events not only do you need to remove the code with the listeners but also completely change the function to remove the code pertaining to it.

Comment: In your case I would make 2 functions an onHover and an onClick function. onHover will handle what happens when you hover. And onClick will handle the action from clicking on the item. There is a rule in computer science 101 called KISS Keep It Simple Stupid. The more complex a function it the harder it will be to modify going down the road.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I continue to set up 100 event listeners for 100 buttons for "on click." and 100 event listeners for "on hover" and point them to two functions? That's pretty much the way i have it now, There's gotta be a way to optimize.

Comment: yes, you need one listener for one event, there is no other way to do it. If you can standardize your button instance names then you can use a loop to set the listeners at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add `CLICK` and `MOUSE_HOVER` listeners in button class and in event handler for them dispatch `CustomEvent`.
Next on the stage where you are listening for all this `CLICK` and `HOVER` events I'll `addEventListener` for this custom `Event` and in one of the parameters pass which action you want to do.

So 1st you need `ButtonCustomEvent` class with const and extra param:

```
public class ButtonCustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "ButtonCustomEvent::CUSTOM_EVENT";

    private var _customParam:String;


    public function ButtonCustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
    {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }


    public function get customParam():String 
    {
        return _customParam;
    }

    public function set customParam(value:String):void 
    {
        _customParam = value;
    }
}
```

Next in your button class:

```
public class MyButtonClass extends Sprite
{
    public function MyButtonClass ()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleEvent);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, handleEvent);
    }


    public function handleEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var myEvent:ButtonCustomEvent = new ButtonCustomEvent(ButtonCustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, true);
        myEvent.customParam = event.type;
        dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
}
```

And then if class where you are adding listeners for ~100 buttons you can do now:

```
addEventListener(ButtonCustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT, handleEvent);

public function handleEvent(event:ButtonCustomEvent):void
{
    if(event.customParam == MouseEvent.CLICK)
    {
        //DO something
    }
    else if(event.customParam = MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER)
    {
        //Do Something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I know how to do that. Can you provide a sample?